# Closing a UDP Socket when using Non-Blocking IO

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, nonblocking

The following code opens a socket, sets it to be non-blocking and sends some data over it using UDP, then closes the socket:

```
int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
sendto(fd, str.c_str(), str.length(), 0,
     (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
close(fd);
```

Is there any issue associated with closing the file descriptor as soon as the call to sendto() has completed given that it's non-blocking?

I'm also interested in any thread-safety considerations with doing the above in multiple threads concurrently?

Comment: As long as another thread doesn't touch `fd` after that `close` call, you'll be fine.

Comment: Your issue is with not checking the return value of `sendto`: especially since you set the socket to non-blocking mode, you cannot assume that _anything at all_ has "completed" just because `sendto` has returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any issue associated with closing the file descriptor as soon
>   as the call to sendto() has completed given that it's non-blocking?

No problems there -- once `sendto()` has returned (with a non-error return value), your data has been copied into a system buffer and can be considered "sent".  Closing the socket will not prevent the data from going out.

> I'm also interested in any thread-safety considerations with doing the
>   above in multiple threads concurrently?

No problems there either -- since there is no data-sharing across threads, there are no race conditions possible.